# The meaning of "April moon"

Tags: meaning, metaphors, lyrics

There are words in the song "Mad about You" by Sting

> A stone's throw from Jerusalem
>   I walked a lonely mile in the moonlight
>   And though a million stars were shining
>   My heart was lost on a distant planet
>   That whirls around the **April moon**
>   Whirling in an arc of sadness
>   I'm lost without you. I'm lost without you

Does the *[April moon](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNTorywSgQ2BLtZWAWcoOxc1_RhunQ%3A1569002286634&ei=LhOFXYW0JqTgkgXExqqgAw&q=%22April%20moon%22&oq=%22April%20moon%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30l6j0j0i67l3.4933.8259..9070...0.0..0.81.158.2......0....1..gws-wiz.UxYBfX2F2bM&ved=0ahUKEwiFg8n__N_kAhUksKQKHUSjCjQQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)* means something special? Google does not enlighten.

Comment: I've previously tried half-heartedly to figure this out because of the Sam Brown song (and album) called April Moon, but didn't come up with much. A full moon in April is also called a Full Pink Moon, and is supposed to coincide with the appearance of certain pink spring flowers (in the Northern Hemisphere, obviously), but that doesn't seem related to the lyrics of either song.

Comment: I know of no planetary bodies encircling the full moon of April, nor any other. Satellites revolve around their primaries, not vice versa. This is therefore about the interpretation of song lyrics, which is a topic that is beyond our site scope.

Comment:  This question isn't any more opinion-based than asking what the "A" means in *The Scarlet Letter* or what the name "Jim Conklin" means in the *The Red Badge of Courage.*

Comment: @Nancy the beauty of songs and poetry, is they mean different things to different people. You may well be right that April moon represents Jesus Christ, but none of your links prove it indefinitely, it is your interpretation. `I'm also not saying that "April moon" might not mean something else in another context.` My interpretation is that April represent spring, rebirth, and, ultimately, youth and the sadness of loss contrasts with the beauty of the moon.  Only the author, Sting, could say which interpretation is closest.

Comment:  Exactly, @Mari-LouA, Sting could say because he did, in fact, mean something, meaning this is a fact-based question.  If you don't like my answer, that's another issue.  My answer doesn't change the question or that it's fact-based, not opinion-based. 

Answer (score 4):

I think in the Sting song, which starts with "A stone's throw from Jerusalem," the phrase "the April moon" is metaphorically referring to God, or Jesus Christ.

Both [Passover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover#targetText=The%20Passover%20begins%20on%20the,April%20of%20the%20Gregorian%20calendar.&targetText=Passover%20is%20a%20spring%20festival,after%20the%20northern%20vernal%20equinox.) and [Easter](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/determining-easter-date.html#targetText=In%20325%20CE%2C%20the%20Council,21%20for%20the%20vernal%20equinox.) are determined by the first full moon after the vernal equinox.  That's why Passover and Easter are usually in April, Passover lasting a week and the first Easter (i.e., the Resurrection of Jesus Christ) having come the Sunday after Passover in Jerusalem.

The idea that it refers to God or Jesus is further underscored by the fact that the moon itself in Christianity is a symbol of [Jesus Christ](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%2021%3A25&version=KJV)--God the father is the Sun, Jesus Christ the moon, and the Holy Ghost the stars--and that symbolism includes the appearance of a blood moon being symbolic of the Crucifixion and the moon turning to blood being symbolic of the [Second Coming](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%206%3A12-17&version=KJV).

I'm not Bible thumping.  I'm also not saying that "April moon" might not mean something else in another context.  I'm just saying that in this context, it appears to be a loose, metaphorical reference by an artist in that artist's work to God or to Jesus Christ, making that planet tragically heaven-adjacent, inescapably drawn to and even very close to heaven while never getting to heaven because of being locked in orbit forever away from heaven, a scenario that is itself metaphoric of the main character of the song in relation to the one that character loves or desires, whether God, a lover, or whomever.

Comment: Hello, 361. Can you kindly add links to material corroborating that (1) 'the moon itself in Christianity is a symbol of Jesus Christ'--(2) 'God the father is [represented by] the Sun'...? I'm fairly sure I've come across these symbolisms before. I'm a little concerned about the claim about the stars symbolising the Holy Spirit; I'm more familiar with the idea that they symbolise angels. // On ELU, we prefer that answers be backed up by supporting references (not just references that address the same general area).

Comment: User361733 (i.e. Nancy) has left the room @EdwinAshworth.